# Why do I keep getting ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'.?

Tags: python, python-import

Whenever I have to import from src module, this error occurs.

I'm trying to import in data_ingestion.py

Structure:

```
src/  
    components/
        data_ingestion.py
```

This is the code I am working on:

```
import os
import sys
from src.exception import CustomException
```

This is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/...../src/components/data_ingestion.py", line 4, in <module>
    from src.exception import CustomException
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'
```

I tried adding the module's directory to the sys.path list, to no effect.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: It's unusual to call your project `src`. I recommend naming it something more meaningful instead of `src`.

Comment: @joanis can you clarify?

Comment: Python doesn't consider a directory a module unless it has an `__init__.py` file. Try adding a blank `__init__.py` to `src`.

Comment: Actually there is a package named `src` see: https://pypi.org/project/src/

Comment: @MSH - but that would only be a problem if you installed it. And then you may get the wrong import, not ModuleNotFound.

Comment: The error message says that data_ingestion is in a subdirectory "components", not at the same level as ./src as you claim.

Comment: Does the src folder have an `__init__.py`? Is the absolute path to `src` known to the python interpreter?

Comment: @Henry it's already there

Comment: I solved this by taking out the ''data_ingestion.py'' file from src

Comment: @NilsLindemann I'm just a beginner, still a lot to learn

Comment: It was your faulty tree diagram that confused us.  You MEANT to say that components was inside of src, and data_ingestion.py was inside of components, but that's NOT what it says.

Comment: @Fathima NP, we all were and are. Regarding your problem, reading [Regular Packages](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#regular-packages) may be helpful for future reference.

Comment: @TimRoberts I tried doing the tree but couldn't. This is the first time I'm posting something here so sorry for any confusion

Comment: @NilsLindemann Ty. But I have also tried renaming the directories earlier tho, I got the same error then.

Comment: @Fathima Python needs to know the absolute path to packages which you want to import. A regular file system folder becomes a python package, when it contains an `__init__.py`.

Comment: Regarding _needs to know the absolute path_, see [The initialization of the sys.path module search path](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys_path_init.html). My personal favorite is adding a `*.pth` file to the site-packages, which contains paths to my own packages.

Answer (score 0):

You have to append the directory of the module in the sys.path. Try this:

```py
// data_ingestion.py
import os
import sys
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))))
from src.exception import CustomException
// ...
```

**EDIT:**
Now that the question is rectified, i think you need to do this in your data_ingestion.py:

```py
from ..exception import CustomException
```

The `..` notation goes up one level in the package hierarchy to access the `exception` module from within the `data_ingestion` module.

At last make sure that both `data_ingestion.py` and the `exception` module are part of the same Python package structure (i.e., both have `__init__.py` files), and this relative import should work.

Comment: @TimRoberts - I think he does. `data_ingestion.py` is in the `components` subdirectory.  Parent is "components" but the directory holding 'src" is one higher.

Comment: Hmm, missed that.  I would have used `..` in that case.